# Can I get Schengen visa after being convicted and deported from UK 12 years ago?

Tags: uk, schengen, europe, schengen-visas, deportation

12 years ago, I was convicted for false document deception for 12 months and was deported from the UK to Kenya. However, I didn't disclose my real details including DOB throughout the incident, I only gave different details. Now I just got a new passport with my real details and real DOB. Can I travel to Schengen countries like France, Germany etc? Will they discover my conviction and deportation through fingerprints? Thanks.

Comment: Have you given biometrics previously in connection with a Schengen visa?

Comment: I have never applied for Schengen visa in my entire life.

Comment: The C-Visa application does not ask about convections or deportation. If  asked in a interview you must inform them. Clearing your UK travel record, if possible,  might be wise. (Seperate question)

Comment: How do I clean that?

Comment: @Kelly The UK will have your biometrics. The only way to clean your travel record with Her Majesty's Government is to make a successful visa application. Changing your passport and other details won’t make your history disappear.